# Remove elements List<String> inside of a HashMap in constant time

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, concurrentmodification

**Manged to solve my problem. Instead of removing from the List I created classes containing the lists, the classes also contained an index which I incremented each time instead of removing the first element.**

I'm trying to implement the Stable marriage algorithm.

I have a `men = HashMap<String, List<String>` where I loop over `men.keySet()`

When a certain condition is met I get a key, and I'm supposed to remove the first element of the list with that key:

```
int someCondition = listIWantToModify;
List<String> temp = men.get(listIWantToModify);
temp.remove(0);
men.replace(listIWantToModify, temp)
```

I want to remove the first element from the one of the lists inside the HashMap. What happens is that I get `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` which I guess comes from the fact that I both remove and get items from the List in the same loop. When I call the following code:

```
List<String> replaceWithP = men.get(currentPartner);
replaceWithP.remove(0);
men.replace(currentPartner, replaceWithP);
```

I tried to do the following:

```
List<String> replaceWithP = new ArrayList<>(men.get(currentPartner));
replaceWithP.remove(0);
men.replace(currentPartner, replaceWithP);
```

But the algorithm is supposed to be O(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst case and I was told that when I create the new ArrayList it is O(n) thus making my algorithm O(n<sup>3</sup>) in the worst case.

Is there anyway I can modify the list inside in constant time without getting the exception or do I need to rethink the whole structure of my implementation?

If so I'd love some suggestions on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the men.replace line at all in the first example. You're directly modifying the list that's in the map. No need to put the same list in again.

Answer (score 0):

The first item of an ArrayList cannot be removed in constant time. The last one can be. This operation removes an entry from the map in constant time:

```
List<String> temp = men.get(currentPartner);
temp.remove(temp.size()-1);
```

If you need to remove the first item, you should use a different data structure, such as ArrayDeque.